# How can I implement text classification for this problem?

Tags: text-classification, topic-model

Given a collection of documents - each corresponding to some economic entity - I am looking to extract information and populate a table with predetermined headings. I have a small sample of this already done by humans and I was wondering if there's an efficient way to automatise it. Grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Caution: it depends on what the data looks like, but in general this can be complex and it might not work well.

The general task is [sequence labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling): the system is supposed to annotate a text and identify specific spans of text as the target categories. The most standard task is [Named Entity Recognition (NER)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition), for which there are many libraries available. You would have to train a custom model using your labelled data (in the specific format expected by the system). In general a model needs a fair amount of example to capture the patterns properly, it's not sure at all that this can work with only a small amount of data.